# I get an error whilst trying to load table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I get these errors whilst trying to load the table
'Uncaught ReferenceError: usersArray is not defined
at loadUsers (trgames.js:20:17)
at trgames.js:22:1' and 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange (trgames.js:15:29)'
i've checked everything

```js
var userTbody=document.getElementById('user-tbody');

function loadUsers(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
         var userJSON=this.responseText;
         var usersArray=JSON.parse(userJSON);
         var tobodyHtml="";
         for(let index = 0; index < usersArray.lenght; index++) {
             const user = usersArray[index];
             tobodyHtml="<tr><td>"+user.id+"</td><td>"+user.username+"</td><td>"+user.password+"</td><td>"+user.birthdate+"</td></tr>";
             console.log(tobodyHtml);
         }
         userTbody.innerHTML=tobodyHtml;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8279/users", true);
    xhttp.send();
    console.log(usersArray);
}
loadUsers();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/trgames.css">
          
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
           <script src="js/trgames.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.5/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-8cU710tp3iH9RniUh6fq5zJsGnjLzOWLWdZqBMLtqaoZUA6AWIE34lwMB3ipUNiTBP5jEZKY95SfbNnQ8cCKvA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
           <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">
              <img src="download.png" alt="Avatar Logo" style="width:40px;" class="rounded-pill"/> </a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav"> 
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Game Register</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Categories</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">User List</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Most Popular</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Most Downloads</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <table id="user-table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Id</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Password</th>
                   <th>Birthday</th>
               </tr>
           </thead> 
           <tbody id="user-tbody">

          </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Where have you put the script? Is it included in the header? The chances are, your 'user-tbody' is not rendered before the `getElementById('user-tobdy')` is executed.

Comment: it’s included in header

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the `user-tobdy` to completely render before you try to reference it from your script.

**Solution 1**

**Use event listeners** to wait until the page is fully rendered:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // this code will run after the dom is rendered
    loadUsers();
});
```

reference `user-tbody` inside your loadUsers function.

```
function loadUsers(){
    var userTbody=document.getElementById('user-tbody');
    //..... rest of your logic
}
```

**Solution 2**

[defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) your link execution.

Comment: it fixed the first error but the array error is still happening

Comment: @Zombotan When you log your array; its probably not even declared; you need to declare it before you call it. In your case you are calling the array before it is declared. So declare the array at the beginning of the method or access the array inside the `onReadyStateChange` callback

Comment: ok the errors are gone but the table won't fill but i get the console log

Comment: You need to append to your `tobodyhtml` like so `tobodyHtml += "<tr>...</tr>"`. Also, if you are trying this on IE browser; `tbody` is considered `readonly` and you wont be able to change the content. Try a different browser or a workaround.

Comment: OK I'm trying this on opera but is what you mean tobodyHtml+="<tr><td>"+user.id+"</td><td>"+user.username+"</td><td>"+user.password+"</td><td>"+user.birthdate+"</td></tr>";"